# Solve the following initial boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)$$

$$u(0, t) = 0$$

$$u(L, t) = 0$$

$$u(x, 0) = 3\sin \bigg(\frac{\pi x}{L} \bigg) - \sin \bigg(\frac{3\pi}{L} \bigg)$$

So I know the infinite series solution and I know that we have to multiply by $\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ to get the orthogonality, But how to apply this method with two sine functions in the initial condition confuses me.

Do we separate the two and treat them independently or no?

Comment: Are you sure $u(x,0) = ... - \sin(\frac{3 \pi}{L})$ and not $u(x,0) = ... - \sin(\frac{3 \pi x}{L})$?

Comment: Have you calculated the general solution?

Comment: use the fact $u = e^{-kn^2t/L^2} \sin (nx/L)$ solves $u_t = u_{xx}$ and the principle of super position.

Comment: @Chinny84, thanks. it is too late to edit the comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$
T(t) = C\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_n^2t}\\
X(x) = A_n\cos \left(\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{k}}x\right) + B_n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{k}}x\right)
$$

applying $u(0,t) = T(t)X(0) = 0 \implies X(0) = 0$

$$
X(0) = A_n \implies A_n = 0
$$
thus the solution is of the form
$$
u(x,t) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}D_n\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_n^2t}\sin\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{k}}x\right)
$$

Using the second condition
$$
u(L,t) = D_n\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_n^2t}\sin\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{k}}L\right) = 0
$$
thus
$$
\lambda_n = \frac{n\pi\sqrt{k}}{L}
$$
therefore we have (superposition)
$$
\begin{align}
u(x,0) &=&  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}D_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\\
 &=&3\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{L}\right)
\end{align}
$$

thus
$$ 
D_n =
\begin{cases}
3,  & \text{if $n$=1} \\
-1, & \text{if $n$=3}\\
0, & \text{for all other $n$}
\end{cases}
$$
thus
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}D_n\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{n^2\pi^2k}{L^2}t}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)
$$